# MySQL - stop updating DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP column

Tags: mysql, replace, timestamp, default

I have two date time columns in my database:
`inserted` and `updated`

```
inserted timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
updated   timestamp -------------------------
```

Primary column is ID.

I run SQL command:

```
REPLACE INTO TABLE1 (id,name,updated) VALUES ('1','test1',NOW())
```

And this is OK:
inserted column get current time upon the first INSERT
updated columns is also set to current time because it is set in REPLACE command.

If I run second command to update name, then updated column is being updated properly but also and `INSERTED` column is updated also. I do not want that!!!

```
REPLACE INTO TABLE1 (id,name,updated) VALUES ('1','test2',NOW())
```

How to stop `inserted` column to be updated automatically once the REPLACE command is being run? What change on column INSERTED in mysql database should be done? I must use REPLACE sql or any synonym for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

`replace` deletes the old record and inserts a new one.

If you want to update an existing record use `update` instead:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 
SET name = 'test2',
    updated = now()
where id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update a field without write-in SQL command. You need to create that column like that:

```
`inserted` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

But this one works for Update operations not Replace operations.

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. See Section 13.2.6, “INSERT Syntax”.

Detailed explanations here, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html